# how to initiate a pdf download with an api call from react frontend to a drf backend - django rest framework

Tags: python, reactjs, django, django-rest-framework, xhtml2pdf

I have an app that uses django rest framework for the backend and react for the frontend. I use the react production build and integrate it with django to serve it. My app has an download pdf functionality. I am using **xhtml2pdf** for generating pdfs. I refered a tutorial and wrote the below codes to generate the pdf which working fine for the time being

**react code** below the href points to the url in django

```js
 <DownPdf href={`/${cat}/download-pdf/${id}/`}>
          <i className="far fa-file-pdf"></i> Download PDF
 </DownPdf>
```

**urls.py**

```py
 path('download-pdf/<str:pk>/', views.download_citation_as_pdf, name='download-pdf'),
```

**views.py**

```py
@api_view(['GET'])
# @permission_classes([IsAuthenticated])
def download_citation_as_pdf(request, pk):
    
    try:
        
        query = Civil.objects.get(id=pk)
        
        serial = Full_Detail_Serial(query, many=False)
        
        print(serial.data['title'])
        
        
        data={
            "serial_data" : query,
            "site":request.get_host()
        }
        
        pdf = render_to_pdf('citationPdfEmail.html', data)
        
        # below returns the pdf view in browser
        # return HttpResponse(pdf, content_type='application/pdf')
        
        # to start force download
        if pdf:
            
            print('pdf is returned to the view')
            
            response = HttpResponse(pdf, content_type = 'application/pdf')
            
            filename = f"sl_%s.pdf" %(serial.data['title'])
            
            content = "inline; filename= '%s'" %(filename)
            
            """
            the double quotes is used to enclose %s beacause
            the title may contain commas and other special characters.
            Single quotes cannot be used to enclose %s and double quotes
            should be used other with it will throw an error.
            """
            content = 'attachement; filename= "%s"' %(filename)
            
            response['Content-Disposition'] = content
            
            print('final response has been generated in the view')
            
            return response
        
        return HttpResponse("not found")
        
        

    except Civil.DoesNotExist:
        
        return Response({"error": "citation does not exist"}, status= status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
        
    
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
      
        return Response({"error": str(e)}, status= status.HTTP_500_INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR)
```

the above view handles the download request when a user clicks the link in the frontend. Now this code only initiates a download when I use a `href` in react build that actually redirect to the url connected to the view.

### My Problem

I want this view to be only accessible when the user is logged in and also add some info in the pdf of the logged in user. But the problem is I cannot make an api call to this view as it does not initiate a pdf download. Without the api call I cannot add the jwt token in the header and use the permission classes to restrict and to get the logged in user.

Hence please suggest me the correct process to use this view along with react build to restrict the view only for a logged in user and initiate a download using an api call.

**Edit: The reponse that I get when I try to make an api call** I have pasted just some lines as it is almost of the same pattern for all the lines(more than thousands of lines).

```
%PDF-1.4
%���� ReportLab Generated PDF document http://www.reportlab.com
1 0 obj
<<
/F1 2 0 R /F2 3 0 R /F3 4 0 R /F4 210 0 R
>>
endobj
2 0 obj
<<
/BaseFont /Helvetica /Encoding /WinAnsiEncoding /Name /F1 /Subtype /Type1 /Type /Font
>>
endobj
3 0 obj
<<
/BaseFont /Times-Bold /Encoding /WinAnsiEncoding /Name /F2 /Subtype /Type1 /Type /Font
>>
endobj
4 0 obj
<<
/BaseFont /Times-Roman /Encoding /WinAnsiEncoding /Name /F3 /Subtype /Type1 /Type /Font
>>
endobj
5 0 obj
```

Comment: what is the reponse you get when you make an API call to this view?

Comment: @MohammadFaisal I have edited the question and added the response please check

Answer (score 1):

I finally got the answer. This is to be handeled from the react end like below

```js
const downloadPdf = () => {
    setProgress(10);
    try {
      setProgress(50);
      axiosInstance
        .get(`/${cat}/download-pdf/${id}/`, {
          responseType: "blob",
        })
        .then((response) => {
          setProgress(90);
          let url = window.URL.createObjectURL(new Blob([response.data]));
          let link = document.createElement("a");
          link.href = url;
          link.setAttribute("download", `filename.pdf`);
          document.body.appendChild(link);
          link.click();
          setProgress(100);
        });
    } catch (error) {}
  };
```